# Different colors for text on same label using string format

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xaml code as below:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Id,StringFormat='{0} *'}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
```

here,is this possible to get Id is in one color and * is in another color?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a FormattedText, like this:

```
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="" TextColor="Red"/>
            <Span Text="" TextColor="Blue"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't support bindings. However, you can set the text from the page code behind. If it doesn't work for you, simply use two labels within a horizontal StackLayout.

**UPDATE:**

Now spans are bindable! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.IOS
Use Like this,

```
var attributedText = new NSMutableAttributedString("Complete it in " + HowManySecondsString + " to reach");
var range = attributedText.MutableString.LocalizedStandardRangeOfString(new NSString(HowManySecondsString)); 
attributedText.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, UIColor.Red, range); 
label.AttributedText = attributedText;
```

---